# PytelegramBotApi нужна помощь с просмотренными новостями

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Делаю телеграм бота с помощью библиотеки `pytelegrambotapi`. Сделал Кнопки и Приветствие, а также кнопку `Новости`.

Можно ли так сделать, чтобы пользователь, прочитавший все новости, при очередном нажатии увидел бы сообщение "Для вас новостей нет!"

Как это сделать?

Comment: каким образом определяется есть новости для пользователя или нет? откуда берутся новости?

Comment: Когда нажимаешь на кнопку "Новости" выходят новости

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку брать `id` и если для него нет новостей отправлять "для вас нет новостей".

Comment: Можете пожалуйста дать пример?

Comment: отредактируйте свой вопрос, через `править`, включив в него ваш код, а так же прошу ответить на вопросы из моего первого комментария.

Comment: Подправил вопрос

Comment: кнопка `inline` или `reply`? каждая новость отдельное сообщение или `edit_message`? допустим у вас 4 новости, т.е. все прочитанные это 4 нажатия на кнопку, тогда отслеживайте сколько раз пользователь нажал на кнопку. если вам нужен пример - покажите свой код.

Comment: Кнопка Reply. Если пользователь нажмет на кнопку "Новости" всего лишь 1 раз, то ему придут несколько Новостей одновременно.

Примерно вот так:

    if msg == "Новости":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Блабла бла')
    if msg == "Новости":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Тест")
    if msg == "Новости":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Новости')

И так несколько раз

Вот кнопка:

markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Новости')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(bot.get_me())

news_count = 4  # количество новостей
press_news_count = {}  # словарь с id и количеством нажатий на кнопку Новости


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    markup.row('Новости')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
    if message.text == 'Новости':
        if message.chat.id in press_news_count:  # если id есть в словаре
            if press_news_count[message.chat.id]['press'] < news_count:  # кол-во нажатий у id меньше кол-ва новостей
                press_news_count.update({message.chat.id: {'press': press_news_count[message.chat.id]['press'] + 1}})  # +1 к нажатию
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы нажали на кнопку новости')
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'новостей нет')
        else:
            press_news_count.update({message.chat.id: {'press': 1}})  # если id нет в словаре, запись первого нажатия
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы нажали на кнопку новости')
        print(press_news_count)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)

>>>
{id: {'press': 1}}
{id: {'press': 2}}
{id: {'press': 3}}
{id: {'press': 4}}
{id: {'press': 4}}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам, можно с вами пообщаться ?

Comment: напишите свой логин в телеграм

Comment: Вот @ak1m0vb3ktu7