# Регистрация нажатий клавиш - PyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, python-3.8

У меня есть `inlinekeyboardmarkup` клавиатура, с несколькими `inlinekeyboardbutton` кнопками. Все работает через Callback или `@bot.callback_query_handler`

---

Вопрос: Как можно сделать так, чтобы регистрировать нажатия по кнопке ?

---

Ситуация: При нескольких нажатий на кнопку, она несколько раз обрабатывается и выдает несколько результатов. Нужно чтобы кнопка обработалась 1 раз и был 1 ответ, - если больше нажатий то вывело бы ошибку пользователю.

Comment: после нажатия изменяйте сообщение оставляя тело, но удаляя кнопку. либо записывайте в dict\txt\sqlite что такой `id` нажимал на кнопку и проверяйте наличие при нажатии

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1225621/234134

Answer (score 0):

```
users = []
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def inline_keyboard(call):
    if call.data == 'Ваш callback_data':
        if call.from_user not in users:
            bot.send_message(call.from_user, "То что надо отправить")
        else:
            bot.send_message(call.from_user, "Ошибка")
```